# Parâmetro com valor padrão no Java

Tags: java, funções, parâmetros

Em outras linguagens, como javascript, é permitido fazer uma função passando um parâmetro com um valor padrão, como na seguinte estrutura:

```
function myFunction(value = true){
    //alguma ação
}
```

Tentei fazer o mesmo com Java, só que não é permitido.

```
public void myFunction(Boolean value = true) {
    //alguma ação
}
```

Alguém sabe o porquê ou se tem alguma maneira alternativa?

Comment: Verdade, não a tinha encontrado antes. Irei excluir a pergunta!

Comment: Não exclui não, duplicatas são boas pro site. Principalmente porque a sua pergunta usa termos diferentes, agora se alguém procurar pelo que você perguntou vai conseguir achar a resposta na outra pergunta...